# Preparing coordinates for ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following coordinate Lists:

```
x={{1,2,3},{1,1,1},{2,2}} 
y={{1,2,3},{2,2,2},{1,1}}
```

I want the following List:

```
xy={{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}},{{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}},{{2,1},{2,1}}}
```

So that I could call ListPlot in the following way:

```
ListPlot[xy[[1]]]
```

I know that I can do the following for one coordinate List but am currently failing to generalise:

```
xy=Transpose@{x[[1]],y[[1]]}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: The coordinate lists are not of equal length.

Comment: Try `Transpose[{x, y}, {1, 3, 2}]`.

Comment: @J.M. I edited my post. Your solution only works if all Lists are of the same length

Comment: Then, try `Flatten[{x, y}, {{2}, {3}}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MapThread[Transpose@*List, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 1}}}
> ```